# Atomic Force Microscopy Imaging of Proteins

Tags: proteins, imaging

I was reading about various imaging techniques, and I came across Atomic Force Microscopy (AFM).  It sounds very interesting, and it also sounds like it is capable of imaging proteins (Page 4)

http://www.cma.fcen.uba.ar/files/prepmuestras.pdf

If that's the case, and since AFM can be done with relatively low expense, why haven't more proteins been imaged?  Apparently around 6500 protein structures have been solved via imaging.

If AFM is a viable technique for protein imaging, what would the consequences of using it on a large scale be?